# How could I display a checked checkbox based from it's value in the database?

Tags: php, html, checkbox

I'm new in PHP, could you help me solve my problem?
I'm trying to display the checkbox checked based on its value in the database. I have saved its value as 1 if it's checked and 0 if it's not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<?php

$sql = "SELECT somecol FROM sometable";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$checked = $result['somecol'];

?>

<input type="checkbox" name="somecol" value="1" <?php if ($checked == 1) echo 'checked'; ?> />
```

Comment: Should have a space before checked => echo ' checked';

Answer (score 4):

You can test the field, let's say `$row['col']`, and emit `checked="checked"` if the field contains 1.

```
echo '<input type="checkbox" name="n" value="v"' . ($row['col']==1 ? ' checked="checked"' : '') . '>';
```

- [Use checked="checked"](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/att_input_checked.asp)